# publish method of the Paho MqttClient blocking forever

Tags: java, timeout, mqtt, paho, moquette

This works well to initiate connection and publish the first message:

```
MemoryPersistence persistence = new MemoryPersistence();
client = new MqttClient("tcp://" + IrisProperties.MQTT_SERVER_ADDRESS,
    IrisProperties.MQTT_USERNAME,persistence);
MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
connOpts.setConnectionTimeout(1);
connOpts.setUserName(IrisProperties.MQTT_USERNAME);
connOpts.setPassword(IrisProperties.MQTT_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
connOpts.setCleanSession(true);
client.connect(connOpts);
```

This connection publishes more than 100 messages per second with no problem with this lines:

```
MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(content.getBytes());
message.setQos(qos);
client.publish(topic, message);
```

BUT after a while (in a few minutes) the 3rd line of this method

```
sampleClient.publish(topic, message);
```

**blocks the thread forever even I set the timeout as 1 second.**

I use Moquette as MQTT Broker with websockets.

Comment: Any logs from the broker?

Comment: I can share some logs tomorrow but how can it be related with the broker? If I set a timeout as 1 second then PAHO should continue when the process continue more than 1 second, right?

In addition I decided to move to mosquitto, and now working on installing it with websocket support..

Comment: How have you set the timeout? It's not shown in the code you've given.

Comment: I've just shared my original connect code in question.

Comment: The timeout you are specifying is only for the `connect()` method not publishing.

Comment: So is there anyway to set timeout for publishing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

> client.setTimeToWait(timeToWaitInMillis);

By default this time is -1, so this Blocks the current thread until the action  has completed.The timeout specifies the maximum time it will block the thread for.