# Set Timeout for Publish method of MQTT Paho - Android

Tags: android, timeout, mqtt, publish, paho

In Android, at the moment when I publish something using `MqttAndroidClient`, it waits indefinitely. I want to set a timeout for Publish method, so that I know when it has failed to publish.

Please let me know how to add the timeout.

```
    val mqttClient = MqttAndroidClient(context, BuildConfig.MQTT_URL, clientId, Ack.AUTO_ACK)

    val options = MqttConnectOptions()
    options.userName = BuildConfig.MQTT_USERNAME
    options.password = BuildConfig.MQTT_PASSWORD.toCharArray()
    options.isCleanSession = false
    options.isAutomaticReconnect = false

    mqttClient?.connect(options, object : IMqttActionListener {
                override fun onSuccess(asyncActionToken: IMqttToken?) {}
                override fun onFailure(asyncActionToken: IMqttToken?, exception: Throwable?) {})
```

I don't see the function `setTimeToWait(timeToWaitInMillis);` which is available for `MqttClient`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [publish method of the Paho MqttClient blocking forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866658/publish-method-of-the-paho-mqttclient-blocking-forever)

Comment: @Brits no. I have added some explanation there